# How to use React hooks with firestore

Tags: reactjs, google-cloud-firestore, react-hooks

How to use React hooks to show a only updated data in table ?

Now I can display all the information. But I want to display the data in a table. When the data in firestore is updated, the data will be displayed on the website. so how to use a React Hook on this code to show information to display only a updated data ?

```
import React, { useEffect, useState } from "react";
import { Button } from "react-bootstrap";
import Table from 'react-bootstrap/Table';
import BookDataService from "../../services/book.services";
import "./table.css";


const tableList = () => {
  const [profile, setBooks] = useState([]);
  useEffect(() => {
    getBooks();
  }, []);

  const getBooks = async () => {
    const data = await BookDataService.getAllBooks();
    console.log(data.docs);
    setBooks(data.docs.map((doc) => ({ ...doc.data(), id: doc.id })));
  };

  return (
    <>
      <div className="mb-4">
        <Button variant="success edit" onClick={getBooks}>
          Refresh
        </Button>
      </div>

      {/* <pre>{JSON.stringify(books, undefined, 2)}</pre>} */}
      <Table striped bordered hover variant="dark" size="md">
        <thead>
          <tr>
            <th>RollNo</th>
            <th>Name</th>
            <th>Student ID</th>
            <th>Subject</th>
            <th>Room</th>
            <th>Date</th>
            <th>Time</th>
            {/*<th>Action</th>*/}
          </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
          {profile.map((doc, index) => {
            const timestamp = { nanoseconds: doc.timeStamp.nanoseconds, seconds: doc.timeStamp.seconds }
            const firebasetime = new Date(
              timestamp.seconds * 1000 + timestamp.nanoseconds / 1000000,
            );
            const date = firebasetime.toDateString();
            const timeStamp = firebasetime.toLocaleTimeString();
            console.log(date, timeStamp);
            return (
              <tr key={doc.id}>
                <td>{index + 1}</td>
                <td>{doc.name}</td>
                <td>{doc.sid}</td>
                <td>{doc.Subject}</td>
                <td>{doc.Room}</td>
                <td>{date}</td>
                <td>{timeStamp}</td>
              </tr>
            );
          })}
        </tbody>
      </Table>
    </>
  );
};

export default tableList;
```

Comment: You can make use of the React `useEffect` hook in the table component to show only updated data in the table.

Comment: this is my code [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75372136/how-to-show-data-on-website-in-react-firestore-when-update-timestamp-from-raspbe) can you show some example ? I tried some but it can't show a data

Answer (score 1):

Here is the simple example for show only updated data:

```
import { useState, useEffect } from 'react';

const SimpleTable = () => {
  const [data, setData] = useState([]);

  useEffect(() => {
    const fetchData = async () => {
      const response = await fetch('https://samplejsonholder.test.com/test');
      const data = await response.json();
      setData(data);
    //You can replace this with data source or api call
    };

    fetchData();
  }, []);

  useEffect(() => {
    // Every time the 'data' state updates, this will run.
    console.log('data updated:', data);
  }, [data]);

  return (
    ...
  );
};
```